# What is the most efficient way to structure a data list in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to integrate a list of 25 data that will be displayed in a `RecyclerView`, the user when pressing a value of the 25 will set it to true.

**My question is:**

What is the most efficient way to show this structure (Nest each value or generate a node for the 25 values, etc) ?.

> He left an example of the structure:

```
"activity_Group":{
      "Group1":{
        "-LT9ty7hc9si6x2IempD" : {
            "1" : false,
            "2" : true,
            "3" : false,
            "4" : true,
            "5" : false
        }
      }
    }
```

> example 2

```
"activity_Group":{
       "Group1":{
          "-LT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
              "id" :"1",
              "status" : false
        },
          "-AT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
              "id" :"2",
              "status" : true
        },
          "-CT1trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
              "id" :"3",
              "status" : false
        },
          "-D39trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
              "id" :"4",
              "status" : true
        },
          "-AT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
              "id" :"5",
              "status" : false
        },
    
    }
}
```

Do they have another shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way to show this structure?

We are usually structuring a Firebase Realtime Database, according to the queries that we want to perform. Without knowing what those queries are, it's hard to say which schema is better than another. However, if 25 is a fixed value and a group will always contain those 25 values, then you can use a structure that might look like this:

```
"activity_Group":{
   "Group1":{
      "1" : false,
      "2" : true,
      "3" : false,
      "4" : true,
      "5" : false,
      ...........
      "25" : false
  }
}
```

In this case, there is no need to push those values under that `-LT9ty7hc9si6x2IempD` id.

If you find yourself in a position that you need to add more properties in addition to the 2 (id and status) existing ones, you can definitely use the second schema. Besides that, you'll also be able to query for example, for all the objects that have the "status" property set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using GSON library [https://github.com/google/gson](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) to covert your data to Json object you can further use on-click to change the value to true if false.

Gson tries to map all fields in the Java object to the JSON file it creates and vice versa.

You will find this tutorial useful
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html